# Parametric Equation solving in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I ma trying to solve this cubic equation for the variables a0,a1,a2,a3

```
ParametricNDSolve[{uz[t] == (a0[t]^3 + a1[t]^2 + a2[t] + a3), 
uz[0] ==  0, uz[T] ==  1, uz'[] == 0,  uz'[0] == 0}, {uz}, {t, 0, 
T}, {a0, a1, a2, a3}];
```

but I am getting the following error in mathematica.

> Dependent variables {a0,a1,a2} cannot depend on parameters {a0,a1,a2,a3}.

Which function to use in mathematica to solve the above parametric equation with the given initial conditions and get {a0, a1, a2, a3}

Comment: The parameters must be numbers, not functions.  Also: `uz'[]` has no argument, which is an error in your code, and the equation you wrote is not a differential equation ... For 4 initial conditions you need a 4th order differential equation. Read the examples on the `ParametricNDSolve` documentation page.

Comment: I'd advise first obtaining solutions with fixed parameters and `NDsolve` before transitioning to the parametric form.